# How to convert IPv4 to Integer using CoffeScript?

Tags: javascript, integer, ip, coffeescript

In CoffeeScript how would I go about converting an IP (standard IPv4 127.0.0.1) into an integer?

**EDIT:** Lots of great answers here, thanks everyone!

Comment: @RussellDias Err... that's not very useful (hint: the decimal integer representation of `127.0.0.1` isn't 127001).

Comment: @therefromhere Guess I misunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Coffeescript

```
ipStringToInteger = (x) ->
  res = 0
  (res = res * 256 + Number(y) for y in x.split("."))
  res
```

which compiles down to

```
var ipStringToInteger;
ipStringToInteger = function(x) {
  var res, y, _i, _len, _ref;
  res = 0;
  _ref = x.split(".");
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    y = _ref[_i];
    res = res * 256 + Number(y);
  }
  return res;
};
```

A short pure Javascript implementation is

```
var ipV4StringToInteger = function(string) {
  var parts = string.split(".");

  var sum = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var partVal = Number(parts[i]);
    sum = (sum << 8) + partVal;
  }

  return sum;
};
```

A good pure Javascript implementation is

```
var ipV4StringToInteger = function(string) {
  var parts = string.split(".");
  if(parts.length != 4)
    throw new Error("IPv4 string does not have 4 parts.");

  var sum = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    var part = parts[i];
    if(!part.match("^\\d+$"))
      throw new Error("Non-digit, non-period character in IPv4 string.");

    var partVal = Number(part);
    if(partVal > 255)
      throw new Error("IPv4 string contains invalid value.");

    sum = ((sum << 8) + partVal) >>> 0;
  }

  return sum;
};
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of using `map` to accumulate.  Mapping values assumes no side affect but you are creating one by accumulating within the function.  If you are going to use an approach like this, at least consider `reduce` which is intended to manage the accumulation (aggregation) of a set.  Still, neither `map` nor `reduce` are supported in all browsers (requires Javascript 1.6).  At that point, you might as well just loop IMO.

Comment: I agree that the use of `map` is dirty.  I wholly agree that the loop is the right move for full compatibility.  Looking at MDN for `Array.map` and `Array.reduce` shows that `reduce` is Javascript 1.8 and `map` is 1.6; both are unavailable in IE <= 8 but `map` is available in older FF, Opera, and Safari...

Comment: Yeah, I missed that.  I had thought reduce was part of 1.6... Don't get me wrong, I like map/reduce/filter/etc... but I'd rather not rely on any of them and bring in something like Underscore to ensure that I have the capabilities... but if I am just implementing a function like this (raw), I'd just prefer a loop.  Especially since the CoffeeScript syntax is plenty clean :)

Comment: JS development is just a weird thing.  As for tooling and libraries, I like the Closure compiler but the namespacing in the Closure library is a little annoying sometimes.  If you can live with it, though, it tends to do exactly the right thing, e.g. `goog.array.map` defers to a browser-native implementation of `map` if it is present and falls back on a pure JS implementation; the Compiler takes out the bloat associated with the sesquipedalian namespaced names.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take the bit-shifting approach:

```
ip_to_int = (value) ->
  result = 0

  for part, i in value.split "."
    result |= part << (3-i) * 8

  result
```

To use it is simple:

```
alert ip_to_int "127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert an ip to integer you need the formula

```
(first octet * 256³) + (second octet * 256²) + (third octet * 256) + (fourth octet)
```

Let `ip = '127.0.0.1'`, that could be written as:

```
integer = 0
for octet, i in ip.split('.')
    integer += octet * Math.pow 256, 3-i
```

And it can be simplified using the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:

```
integer = ip.split('.').reduce ((t, n) -> t*256 + parseInt n), 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe @ellisbben hit it, but thought I'd over another JS version with a bit more error checking.

```
function ip2int(ip){
    // split them in to their own numbers
    var octets = ip.split('.');

    // make sure we have a valid IP. (length-wise)
    if (octets.length!=4) return false;

    // begin parsing
    var result = 0;
    for (var v = 1; v <= 4; v++){
        var i = parseInt(octets[v-1],10);

        // valid number?
        if (isNaN(i) || i < 0 || i > 255) return false;

        result += (i * Math.pow(256,(4-v)));
    }
    return result;
}

alert(ip2int('127.0.0.1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another bit shift method.

```
addr='192.168.5.253'.split('.');
ipInt = (+addr[0] << 24) + (+addr[1] << 16) + (+addr[2] << 8) + (+addr[3]);
```

And to reverse it...

```
[ipInt >> 24 & 0xff,ipInt >> 16 & 0xff,ipInt >> 8 & 0xff,ipInt & 0xff].join('.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's JS version, but it's very easy to convert it into CoffeeScript:

```
// 'x.x.x.x' -> number    
function Ip4ToInt(ip4str) {

    var addr = ip4str.split('.');
    if ( addr.length !== 4 || addr.some( (elm) => (parseInt(elm) > 255 || parseInt(elm) < 0 ) ) ) {
        throw new Error('Invalid ip4 string: ' + ip4str);
    }
    return ((addr[0] << 24) >>> 0) + ((addr[1] << 16) >>> 0) + ((addr[2] << 8) >>> 0) + (addr[3]);
}

// number -> 'x.x.x.x'
function IntToIp4(ip4int){
    return [ip4int >> 24 & 0xff,ip4int >> 16 & 0xff,ip4int >> 8 & 0xff,ip4int & 0xff].join('.');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The smallest solution for node.js:

```
function ip2int(ip) {
    var ipint = 0;
    ip.split('.').map(function (e, i) {
        ipint += Math.pow(256, 3-i) * e;
    });
    return ipint;
}
console.log(ip2int('10.1.1.20'));
```